# Parse error "Could not build module 'UIKit'" but the app runs fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode11

I created a new project in Xcode 11, the "Single View app" in objective C. In every class the line `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` is highlighted in red, with the message "Could not build module 'UIKit.'" However the app builds and runs with no problem.

I've read a lot of questions like this on SO from years back, but none with XCode 11 and it doesn't sound like any of them would build without breaking. For me it is purely a parsing issue.

I tried deleting derived data, and I reinstalled XCode multiple times. The last time I went through this tutorial for completely erasing XCode from my computer: https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-macos

Through the rest of the day the issue seemed to be gone. But this morning it's back again.

This seems to be happening with any XCode project I have, including brand new ones with no code changes.

I would just ignore the "errors" but it keeps me from being able to use autocomplete which slows down my workflow a lot.

**Update**
This issue seems to have gone away. I'm not sure why but I'm happy for it.

**Update**
This issue came back again after updating my computer. I have not been able to update Xcode for a while not. I'm not sure if the issue is related

**Update**
I was able to update Xcode, and the issue went away again.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer the question (in the answer field) and be specific about what version of Xcode fixed it. That will be helpful to other Stack Overflow users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Mac to Catalina 10.15.1 and was able to update Xcode to 11.2. After this the parse error discontinued and all of my syntax highlighting is back to normal.